# problemas la extender AppCompatActivity para usar material design

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design

una pregunta. quiero trabajar una aplicación con material design y para eso es necesario hacer un extends AppCompatActivity, pero yo ya realizo un extend ListActivity para los resultados de una web service... ¿qué solución me proponen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usar recyclerview que remplza los listviews o bien si quieres aun usar un listview ponlo dentro de un layout

Answer (score 1):

Pues si quieres usar Material Design yo te sugiero empezar a usar RecyclerView en lugar de ListView y actualizar a los nuevos widgets que te ofrece la librería de compatibilidad.

Si aun no quieres cambiar los widgets bueno aquí tienes un ejemplo de como usar ListView sin extender de ListViewActivty

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328235/how-to-extends-listactivity-where-appcompatactivity-in-android-activity